# Lyx missing parenthesis glyphs

Tags: lyx

When I try to insert parentheses in Lyx, this is the dialog I get:

[image]

The glyphs for the different kinds of parentheses are missing. Any idea of how I can fix this?

Comment: You can just replace the delimiter after the `\left` and `\right`. For example: `\left( \right)`, `\left[ \right]`, `\left\{ \right\}`. Notice the extra `\` on the third example.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik No, you can't do that in LyX.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I was missing the `fonts-lyx` package. Under Ubuntu, fix with:

```
sudo apt install fonts-lyx
```